# Upstream links disappear when fetch refspecs are provided directly in the command line

Tags: git, fetch, upstream-branch

Consider a common scenario where we have two upstream branches set up for two local branches. This can be verified using `git branch --all -vv` which provides the following output:

```
* master                     74d2505 [origin/master] commit_message_X
  my_branch1                 55f5728 [origin/my_branch1] commit_message_Y
```

The corresponding remote-tracking branches are clearly shown above.

Now here is an experiment. I remove the line `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` from `.git/config` and instead run  `git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` *directly* in the command line. Then, I re-ran `git branch --all -vv` only to be surprised by the fact that all the remote-tracking branches within square brackets were gone:

```
* master                     74d2505 commit_message_X
  my_branch1                 55f5728 commit_message_Y
```

At the last part of the experiment, I added the line `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` back to `.git/config` and ran an argument-less fetch `git fetch origin`. The remote-tracking branches got *all* back.

```
* master                     74d2505 [origin/master] commit_message_X
  my_branch1                 55f5728 [origin/my_branch1] commit_message_Y
```

Can anybody help me understand what is going on here? Why is it important to include fetch refspecs in the `.git/config` file and not in the command line? How does `git` exactly establish the remote-tracking branches shown within square brackets in the output of `git branch --all -vv`?

Just in case, here are some relevant parts of the `.git/config` file:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

[branch "my_branch1"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/my_branch1
```

Comment: What shell did you use to enter the `git fetch` command? What behavior does it have on non-match for glob items? (I'm guessing there were no files that matched `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.) Do you have `fetch.prune` set to `true`? What version of Git are you using?

Comment: (I repeated this with an older version of Git, quoting the refspec, so I don't think there's any sh / bash match issues here. This seems like a bug in Git. It's probably version-dependent, but it may exist since 1.8.4 or something.)

Comment: The thing that's happening internally is that the remote-tracking names go away (use `git branch -r` or `git for-each-ref` to observe this). I have fetch.prune set to true globally myself, which may be important.

Comment: @torek Thank you for your responses. Just in case, I use `Git Bash` terminal on Windows 10. As you suggested, I ran `git branch -r` and `git for-each-ref`. I noticed all the remote-tracking branches (starting with `refs/remotes/origin/...`) are still listed. It is just that their _connection_ to the local branches disappears, at least as indicated by the output of `git branch --all -vv`.